# Phonegap + iOS: how to play audio with Media API

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, media, local

i have an audio file test.mp3.

when the file located in "Documents" folder, and i  create my media object like this :media = new Media('documents://test.mp3'); Everything works fine.

but when my audio file located in a subfolder in "Documents" folder, say "Documents/data", and i create my media object like this: media = new Media('documents://data/test.mp3'), i have this error in console: Failed to initialize AVAudioPlayer: (null) . And error code = 4

My question is, how can i play an audio file located in a subfolder in "Documents" folder

**Edited:**

It is fixed in phonegap 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Using phonegap 1.7, just provide the name of the file without any schema. According to the Cordova source code if you don't prefix with any schema (like documents/file) it is relative to your www fold

```
media = new Media('test.mp3');
```

Assuming you have www/test.mp3 file in your project